# Feynman-Kac formula for domains with boundary

Tags: riemannian-geometry, stochastic-processes, heat-equation

As far as I know (I am not an expert), any solution of the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or on a closed Riemannian manifold with the given initial condition can be presented in terms of stochastic integral (Feynman-Kac formula).

I am wondering if there is a generalization of the Feynman-Kac formula to compact Riemannian manifolds with boundary.

> More precisely let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary $\partial M$ (e.g. a bounded domain with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Let $$u\colon M\times [0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$$
>   be a solution of the heat equation $u_t=-\Delta u$ with the boundary conditions
>   $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$, and $u(z,t)$ is a given function of $z\in\partial M,t\in[0,T]$.
>   How to present $u$ in terms of the boundary data using a path integral?

The case of bounded domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is already new to me.

EDIT: As commented by Mateusz Kwasnicki, in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ there are extra difficulties. As far as I understand, they are related to the growth condition of a solution at infinity. Thus at the moment I prefer to restrict the discussion to **compact** manifolds, e.g. bounded domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary.

Comment: I am not an expert either, but here are some thoughts: (1) Not *every* solution has a probabilistic interpretation, just as not *every* solution is given in terms of the heat kernel. (2) Feynman–Kac originally referred to solutions of the heat (or Poisson) equation with a potential; formulae of the form $u(t,x) = \mathbb{E}^x u_0(W_t)$, where $W_t$ is the Wiener process (with absorption or reflection on the boundary, if any), are much older and, if I am not mistaken, attributed to Kakutani.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry on [stochastic processes and boundary value problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_processes_and_boundary_value_problems) apparently confirms this. It is a pity, though, that it does not even link to the entry on the [Feynman–Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula). In fact, both entries require attention of an expert.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: Thank you. In your remark 1) do you refer to domains with boundary or it is also related to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and/or closed manfolds?

Comment: I was thinking about [Tychonoff's counterexample](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/e859feb614cdfd74c454f8d073e00d57/sm6410.pdf), an exotic solution in full space; see also [Chung–Kim](https://doi.org/10.1080/03605309408821054) for a related construction.

Comment: There is a result in Theorem 4.2 in Chatper 7.4 in the book "Stochastic Controls: Hamiltonian Systems and HJB Equations". It states a Feynman-Kac representation for bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.